# tooltip didn't hide after click on element (bootstrap v5.0)

Tags: javascript, tooltip, bootstrap-5, popper

I changed the bootstrap version from 4.5.x to 5.0.1 and also changed the initializing of the tooltips from `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({trigger: 'hover'});`
to

```js
let tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl, {
        container: 'body'
    });
})
```

But the problem that the tooltip is still visible after clicking the elememt with the shown tooltip comes back with version 5.0. I have solved this in version 4.5.x with `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip("hide");` but that doesn't work in version 5.

I tried:

```js
let tooltipElement = document.getElementById('myElementwithTooltip');
let tooltip = bootstrap.Tooltip.getInstance(tooltipElement);
tooltip.hide();
// or
tooltip.dispose();
```

But that didn't help properly.
I have many tooltips on the website some of them open a dialog some of them are as discription of a column header in a datatable plugin (with sort function).

The tooltips on the [bootstrap website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/) have the same problem. After clicking the element the tooltip doesn't disapear.

I would be very grateful for any ideas or suggestions.

Comment: Do you want them to trigger on hover or click?

Comment: on hover. That's working, but if I click the element because it is a button, than the shown tooltip doesn't disapear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the tooltip on hover then make sure you specify `hover` as the trigger option.

```
let tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl, {
        container: 'body',
        trigger : 'hover'
    });
})
```

Then you won't have the click problem.

[Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/ieY47Csax6)

Also, `hide()` isn't going to work the way you've shown unless it's tied to an event handler.

Comment: This doesn't answer the main problem which is hiding the tooltip after a click. I've been struggling with this problem for a couple of hours, tried a lot of answers and my main  conclusion is that using the new bootstrap 5 Tooltip() constructor simply doesn't work in such cases. Using jQuery instead will work - `$(tooltipElement).tooltip()` and `$(tooltipElement).tooltip('dispose')` did the trick for me.